# Use singletons in akka scala actor

Tags: multithreading, scala, actor, akka

I have an actor that is delegating calls to a stateful singleton. The singleton is stateful since it is maintaining a map of objects. This singleton object is used just in the actor and in a class (not actor) where I am retrieving one object in this map (so just thread safe read).

```
class MyActor extends Actor{
  def receive()={
    case ACase => singleton.amethod()  
    case BCase => singleton.bmethod()
     }
 }

val singleton = new MyActorLogic

class MyActorLogic{
 val map:Map[String, Object] = Map()
 def amethod()=//alter the map

 def readMap(value:String) = map(value)    }
```

Could there be any side effects/problems?
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do **not** do that for any reason in the world.
Trust me.

If you need that sort of things use Agent instead, that's what they are good for:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.4/scala/agents.html

Comment: I have resolved putting a map into the actor and querying the actor. So the singleton has been incorporated into the actor and doesn't expose anything. I am starting thinking that actors and dependency injection are not good friends. Am I right?

Comment: DI works just fine, we even have a Spring-integration and a Guice-integration.

Comment: A brief explanation would make this a much more useful answer. What is the reasoning behind not following the approach in the question? Why is it inferior to , say encapsulating the map in the actor or using Agents?

Comment: Could you please explain the reasoning behind your enthusiastic recommendation to avoid the OP's initial implementation, @ViktorKlang?

Comment: The current version of Akka 2.5.1 suggests that agents will be deprecated in future releases http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.1/scala/agents.html it would be nice if you could update your answer to reflect the current developments.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, using `MyActorLogic`, armed with a simple mutable map, from multiple threads, may lead to concurrent modification exception (when one thread is traversing the map, whilst another's modifying it).

You could do the following to avoid problems :

1. Put the map into the actor (as a private member). In `Akka`, you're not working with the `Actor` instance directly (but rather accessing it through a proxy - `ActorRef`). In this case, safe access to the map will not only be guaranteed by the actor, that always processes one message at a time - other threads won't be able to access private members even through reflection.
2. You can make update/retrieval methods of `MyActorLogic` thread-safe (e.g., making them `synchronized`)
3. You can use old-good `ConcurrentHashMap`
4. Instead of `val map:mutable.Map` you can use `var map:immutable.Map`. Thus, multiple threads accessing `map` may occasionally work with a stale data, but there will be no concurrent modifications (copy-on-write approach).

---

Just for the note, true singleton would be:

```
object MyActorLogic{
 val map:Map[String, Object] = Map()
 ...
```

Comment: I will follow the first suggestion. I am using the new operator because object are not mockable for unit tests. But I am using cake pattern as well, so probably I will be able to mock objects with cake pattern. Thanks

Comment: I will never endorse something like that. It's just begging for problems.